# Analogue of "orphan" for someone who's lost their siblings

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, analogy

As per title - is there such a word?

Either a noun:

> John is an ??????  (his only brother died when he was 3)

or verb (or past tense as an adjective):

> John  was ????ed today (his only sister died today)

Comment: The first would be a noun. I don't know of any such word/s.

Comment: The origin of the word *orphan* seems to be the Latin *orphanus* which means "without parents" or "fatherless". So perhaps the latin word *unigenita* meaning "only child" would be a root word? I don't think there is a word for losing all siblings.

Comment: @SubmittedDenied Perhaps then "unigenitified" or "unigenitiated" and for a noun "unigenitian" (following the "an" ending of orphan)?

Comment: One of my friends is a bereaved sibling. I have suggested we coin the term "sidow" for her - like a widow, but for siblings.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This isn't a discussion forum, but a Q&A site which favors definitive, well-supported answers, and while *sidow* might be an interesting neologism, it isn't in common use. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of the goals and practices of our site.

Answer (score 3):

They are often mentioned as "**bereaved sibling**".

For example, in this book:

*Sibling Grief: Healing After the Death of a Sister Or Brother - By P. Gill White*

---

> **[bereaved](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bereaved)** *adj.* Suffering the loss of a loved one: *the bereaved family.*

Comment: Sure, but the term doesn't indicate the person lost *all* of their siblings

Answer (score 1):

Someone with no siblings is called an **only child**.  I have heard an elderly woman say, when her last sibling had died, "Now I have become an only child."